# BAT. SSH. Передача команд на выполнение

Tags: ssh, bat, putty

Всем доброго времени суток!

Есть bat-ник для подключения к удаленному хосту через ssh:

```
start "" "C:\bla\bla\putty.exe" login@host -pw password
```

Он благополучно выполняется и каждый раз я нахожусь в домашней директории. И каждый раз делаю `cd bla/bla/bla` в ту или иную директорию.

Вопрос: можно ли в bat-нике указать перечень команд, которые должны быть выполнены после подлючения к хосту?

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 - выполнить набор комманд при логине. То есть в одном из файлов `~/.bashxxx` (в зависимости от шелла, могут иметь другое название) можно написать набор команд, которые будут выполняться при логине на удаленном сервере.

Вариант 2 - передать `putty -m "cmd_list.txt"` в котором прописать набор комманд, которые следует запусить на сервере вместо шелла, например `cd /my/path ; /bin/bash`.

Comment: Пробовал, используя файл с командами - не выполняет их. Сам файл видит, а команды не выполняет. Может быть проблема из-за настроек сервера? Как вариант: запрет на выполнение команд, передаваемых параметрами?